# Use of hex 0xdeadbeef in C++ std::vector construcor

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

I was going through some tutorials for OpenCL with the C++ wrapper and one of the sample codes uses the following to define some vectors

```
std::vector<float> h_a(LENGTH);
std::vector<float> h_b(LENGTH);
std::vector<float> h_c(LENGTH, 0xdeadbeef);
```

For the third definition they included the hex 0xdeadbeef. This third vector is being used to store the output returned by the kernel in the OpenCL program and it remains uninitialized.

It seems to me to be a memory address being specified, but I cannot see a constructor that allows this in the std library description from here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector
Unless it is related to the allocator type.

I would like to ask if this is simple specifying a memory address for that particular vector, if there is some significance to the choice of 0xdeadbeef(a wiki article on magic numbers says that it is just easy to locate in a memory dump which matches this case where we have an uninitialized vector), which particular constructor it is using for the vector initialization and if possible what would be the motivation for defining the vector in this way.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Isn't that just the length and default value for each element? so `vector( size_type count, 
                 const T& value = T(),
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());` or `vector( size_type count, 
                 const T& value,
                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());` depending on c++ version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't specify a memory address, it just specifies an integer constant in hexadecimal notation. This constant is then implicitly converted to a float, to call the version of vector's constructor that takes a length and an initial value for the elements. (Note that the float is whichever float value is closest to the value of 0xdeadbeef (3735928559 in decimal), not the float with the same bit pattern as 0xdeadbeef.)

Comment: Yes this is correct. They are all initialized to 3735928576.0000. I think the motivation was to easily confirm if the OpenCL Kernel did write their result into the output array at the end. Thank you for the answer. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
         vector( size_type count,

             const T& value,
             const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

It initializes the contents of the vector

Answer (score 0):

The point is that the word deadbeef jumps out at you when looking at debug output. It's often used to indicate a value that hasn't been initialized yet. If you see it in debug output, chances are very high that you have uninitialized data.

However, in this case the value is used to initialize an array of floating point values. Once the value has been converted to float then it won't stand out. Indeed in this case it is converted to the closest float to `0xdeadbeef` which in decimal is `3735928559`, and the closest float to that is `37359285576.0f`. Go figure!

Perhaps whoever wrote this code has been in the habit of initializing everything to `0xdeadbeef` and not adjusted to this data being floating point.

Comment: The problem is that this value will be converted to a float and is very unlikely to ever show up in debug output.